# What is the best way to update an attribute with integer values in a angularJS form?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to create a form using angularJs, I have some attributes which is of integer type.

for example, I have variable called admin_events, it has 3 values, 0, 1, 2 to indicate the user's right/permisson to access different files. The number 0 means no right, 1 means view only, 2 means full right. 
Now I want to create a form for editing this attributes for the administrator. 
How should I go about doing this?
I am thinking of using a angularJs to make 3 radio buttons/checkboxes of 1,2,and 3, so that the administrator can just click on the option and it will update the attributes.

Anyone has any suggestion on what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I personally would make a dropdown with ng-options you can display the text according to the values

Comment: but I have a question about ng-options, I cannot use that because my admin_event is just a variable that contains an integer value, it is not an array of 3 integers. So I cannot ng-repeat the options in admin_event.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible approach. See inline comments for explaination.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {

    // set up your model
    $scope.allPermissions = [
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "ADMIN", selected: false },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "READ", selected: false },
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "WRITE", selected: false } ];

    // Use $watch to detect changes in the model. 
    // But you might as well want to call this from an event or whatever...
    $scope.$watch('allPermissions', function(newval, oldval){
      if (oldval != newval)
        {   
          // only return the checked values using $filter
          var selectedPermission = $filter('filter')($scope.allPermissions, {selected: true});

          // 'selectedPermission' will return a list of all selected permissions. 
          //  Use 'selectedPermission[0].id' to return the first value.
          $scope.admin_events = selectedPermission[0].id;

        }
    },true);

});
```

And in your HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <p ng-repeat="permission in allPermissions">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.selected"/>
        {{permission.name}}
    </p>
    admin_events: {{admin_events}}

</body>
```

Comment: ok, I tried this. It looks pretty good, but is it possible to only restrict only 1 check box to be checked at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to use a range type input to achieve the selection. It is much easier to implement.

```
  <input ng-model= "user.activities.events" name="activities.events" type="range" max="2" min="0" class="form-control">
```

But i think @sjokkogutten's answer is not bad too. But the checkboxes are not mutally exclusive. Thanks anyway @sjokkogutten.